# Communicating between browser and local application - Secure connection?

Tags: javascript, html, go, ssl-certificate

Currently creating an application launcher and updater based on a web page. Knowing the limitations of browsers (security reasons), for my project I needed to have a local application to control the update and the creation of the OS process.

While testing and researching for a good amount of time; Now I have a working local-app, *written in Go*, that can create a process and kill it from an `ajax` **`POST`** request. I prepared some code to show, how my current attempt looks like (nothing fancy) :

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>api_test</title>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h2 id="statusText"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

#### js/script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("Hey! ;)");
  tryConnection();
});

function tryConnection() {
  var statusReq = $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:9091/api/test",
    dataType: "json"
  });

  statusReq.fail(function(){
    $('#statusText').text("Fail");
    setTimeout(tryConnection, 5000);
  });

  statusReq.done(function(json){
    $('#statusText').text(json.status);
    console.log("Integer result: " + json.result);
    setTimeout(tryConnection, 10000);
  });
}
```

#### Local application, app.go

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "encoding/json"
)

type APITest struct {
  Status string `json:"status"`
  Result int `json:"result,omitempty"`
};

func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  TestValue := APITest{Status: "Works!", Result: 123};
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&TestValue);
}

func main() {
  log.Println("Started!");
  http.HandleFunc("/api/test", testHandler);

  err := http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:9091", nil);
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error occured:", err);
  }
}
```

Everything seems to be fine! *But..*

The only problem I currently can't figure out is, How can I actually add support for `https://` connections without the need to carry the compiled binary with a cert and key file? Because I want to implement this feature into a `https://` only website and mixing together `https` and `http` connections, results in a `blocked mixed content` error from browser security restrictions, which is understandable.

Maybe there are some other ways to implement this kind of communication? (to be clear, for `WebSockets` a secure connection is needed too).

Comment: The only way to use https without warnings in a browser, is to use a certificate trusted by the browser.

Comment: Yes of course! I want to use letsencrypt.org, but the point is, that every client needs to download an application for their specific OS, before they are able to use all features of the website. But making this as a download, I need supply the certificate with the corresponding valid key.. as files.